# how to upgrade the android app version one Own SQLite Database without losing the existing data

Tags: android

I need to update my android application in the market to next version.next version i need to update the sqlite DB without losing the exsiting data.

In version one i did not create the tables in runtime instead get the database file from the "assets" folder and copies into the system database path of my application.
Refer to this link 
http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/

next version of my app i have modify the exsting table columns and add extra records and there are few new tables as well.I have updated the data base and copied to asset folder.

This will work for users who buy the app for first time,but not for existing users,my question is how can i update the version one users data base without losing existing data

Sam.

Answer (score 3):

```
   @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, 
    int newVersion) 
    {
        Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion 
                + " to "
                + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        if(oldVersion == 2 && newVersion == 3)
        {
            db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE xyz ADD bobby int default 0");    
        }
        else
        {
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS xyz");
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Prepare sql query to upgrade database.
If database exists then perform updating else copy database from assets.

In tutorial that you provided is such code:

```
    if(dbExist){
        //do nothing - database already exist
    }else{
```

In place where is `//do nothing - database already exist` put your upgrading code.

Comment: so i don't want to update the version number and leave the onUpgrade method as it is?

Comment: You could use `onUpgrade` but you don't need to. In the tutorial that you were based, there are empty onUpgrade and `onCreate`  methods. But I think it would be better to implement `onCreate` and `onUpdate` when you think about upgrading database in future. If so, then refactor your code to use these methods and set db version after creation: `SQLiteDatabase.setVersion(int)`. When you have db version you can benefit from `onUpgrade`.

Comment: this is what i going to do please corret me if i wrong : copying the new data base to asset folder so those who get the app for the first time they have latest DB, and i will add a separate method if the DB is exist and the new version number is 2 i will execute alter table and insert record statmens..

Answer (score 1):

You could try a patch-like solution I describe in this blog post. It will aid with incremental upgrading and will continue to scale as you build more and more versions.

http://www.greenmoonsoftware.com/2012/02/sqlite-schema-migration-in-android/

Answer (score 0):

In your SQLiteHelper class the DATABASE_VERSION variable should be the latest version. Suppose earlier DATABASE_VERSION was 1 and as you are upgrading so it must be 2.

```
DatabaseHelper(Context context)
    {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
```

Now Upgrade the old database version to new Version. **If you don't set the latest version number in the database then onUpgrade(..., ...) will  get called repeatedly.**

```
@Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
    {
        logger.info("DBManager - :::: Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion+ " to "+ newVersion + ", which will modify some old table");


        String sqlFileName = "update_version_1.sql";

        int totalSQLQueries = executeSQLScript(db, sqlFileName);

        logger.info("DBManager - :::: Upgrading database from version - " +"Total " + totalSQLQueries +" queries executed succesfully from " +sqlFileName);

        if(db.getVersion() == oldVersion) {
            db.setVersion(newVersion);
            logger.info("DBManager - :::: DB Version upgraded from " +oldVersion +" to " +newVersion);
        }
    }
```

Your database modification code must be written within a transaction. See the code bellow as an example of using transaction for database upgrade :-

```
    private int executeSQLScript(SQLiteDatabase db, String sqlFileName) 
    {
        int count = 0;

        InputStream inputStream = null; 
        BufferedReader bufferReader = null;

        try
        {
            db.beginTransaction();

            inputStream = localContext.getApplicationContext().getAssets().open(sqlFileName);
            bufferReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String inputLine;

            while((inputLine = bufferReader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                if(inputLine.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("BEGIN;") || inputLine.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("END;"))
                {
                    continue;
                }
                else
                {
                    db.execSQL(inputLine);
                    count = count + 1;
                }
            }

            db.setTransactionSuccessful();
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            if(bufferReader != null)
            {
                try {
                    bufferReader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            if(inputStream != null)
            {
                try {
                    inputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            db.endTransaction();
        }

        return count;
    }
```