# Android Difficulty in upgrading SQlite table without loosing old data

Tags: android, sqlite

My code for creating data base is this...

```
      public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {



// ====================== String Variables ======================
// The Android's default system path of your application database.
private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.example/databases/";
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "test.sqlite"; // Database Name

// ++++++++++++++++++++++ int Variables ++++++++++++++++++++++
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1; // Database Version



// = = = = = = = = = = = Other Variables = = = = = = = = = = ==
private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;
private final Context myContext;
SQLiteDatabase db;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private String privateDirectoryPath;



public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    this.myContext = context;
    //  db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    //this.privateDirectoryPath = privateDirectory;
}
public void db_open()
{
    db = this.getWritableDatabase();
}
/**
 * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own
 * database.
 * */
public void createDataBase() throws IOException {
    boolean dbExist = databaseExist();

    if (dbExist) {
        // do nothing - database already exist
    } else {
        // By calling this method and empty database will be created into
        // the default system path
        // of your application so we are gone a be able to overwrite that
        // database with our database.
        this.getReadableDatabase();
        try {
            copyDataBase(); // call method to copy database
            db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new Error("Error copying database");
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Mrthod to check database is exist or not
 * @return
 */
public boolean databaseExist()
{
    File dbFile = new File(DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME);
    return dbFile.exists();
}

/**
 * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created
 * empty database in the system folder, from where it can be accessed and
 * handled. This is done by transfering bytestream.
 * */
private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
    // Open your local db as the input stream
    InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);

    // Path to the just created empty db
    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;

    // Open the empty db as the output stream
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

    // transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    // Close the streams
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();

}



/**
 * Close Database
 */
@Override
public synchronized void close() {



    if (myDataBase != null)
        myDataBase.close();
    super.close();
}

public void DB_close()
{
    if(db!=null)
        db.close();
}



@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}



}
```

Now when i change new structure of data base from assets ... how it will update in app.. without loosing old data.....
     Please gave me proper giudence...
    Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DbHelper mDHelper = new DbHelper(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION)
please pass version when dbhelper is created.
```

Comment: how can i do that without losing old data?

Comment: don't copy your updated database structure in assets folder.just whenever you change structure please put that query in your onupgrade() and solve your problem.:)

Comment: please upVote my Ans.if you useful it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to override `onUpgrade` method of `SQLiteOpenHelper` class for Upgrading the database.

onUpgrade is basically for handling new db changes(could be new columns addition,table addition) for any new version of your app.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the structure of your database in `onUpgrade` method. Not in `assets` folder. [Reffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6695699/how-to-upgrade-the-android-app-version-one-own-sqlite-database-without-losing-th). [Search](https://www.google.co.in/?gws_rd=cr&ei=ap4yUrHQFsq-rgeNwIDIAg#q=how+to+upgrade+sqlite+database+in+android).

Comment: hi... I have refer this link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6695699/how-to-upgrade-the-android-app-version-one-own-sqlite-database-without-losing-th... But where i have to pass version?

Comment: [this way](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7696839/how-to-upgrade-sqlite-database-in-android)

Comment: how can i do that without losing old data?